# How to set a parameter in a link?

Tags: php, database, mysqli, hyperlink

I have a query from my database for a forum I am working on. For some reason I cannot get the id to show up in the link. I have been wracking my brain trying to figure it out. It works on all my other pages except this one. Here is the code I am using:

```
$topicsql = "SELECT topic_id,topic_subject,topic_date,topic_cat FROM topics
            WHERE topic_cat = " . $row['cat_id'] . "
            ORDER BY topic_date DESC LIMIT 1";

$topicsresult = mysqli_query($con, $topicsql);

if(!$topicsresult)
{
    echo 'Last topic could not be displayed.';
}
else
{
    if(mysqli_num_rows($topicsresult) == 0)
    {
        echo 'no topics yet';
    }
    else
    {

        while($topicrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($topicsresult))
        //Limit the number of characters in the latest topic link
        $subject=   substr($topicrow['topic_subject'], 0, 25);
        $topic=$topicrow['id'];


        echo '<a href="topic.php?id=' . $topicrow['topic_id'] . '">' . $subject . '&hellip;</a><br> on ' . date('m-d-Y', strtotime($topicrow['topic_date']));
 }
}
```

when you hover over the link I just get `topic.php?id=`, but I should be seeing `topic.php?id=24`

Comment: Please mention what do you see on hover.

Comment: when i hover over the link i just get topic.php?id=......I should be seeing topic.php?id=24

Comment: Kindly check if `topic_id` is in `topicrow`; most probably you are messing up with names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
   $query = "SELECT topic_id,topic_subject,topic_date,topic_cat FROM topics
              WHERE topic_cat = ?
              ORDER BY topic_date DESC LIMIT 1";
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query)) {   
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'i', $row['cat_id']);
        /* execute prepared statement */
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);   
        /*bind the result*/
        $stmt->store_result();
        /*Count the rows*/
        if( mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)){
                /*Limit the number of characters in the latest topic link*/
                $link = '<a href="topic.php?id=' . $row['topic_id'] . '">';
                $link .= substr($row['topic_subject'], 0, 25) . '&hellip;</a><br>';
                $link .= 'on '.date('m-d-Y', strtotime($row['topic_date']));
                echo $link;
            }
        }else{
            echo 'Last topic could not be displayed.';
        }   
        /* close statement */
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }else{
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    }
```

Since it is creating the links, it means your query found the rows, if you see that the id is blank it suggest that the column name is not matching.

At this point only you can tell, my advice is to rewrite the code like above, I just wanted to point out the best practices for prepared statement, naming variables, reduce the number variables, indentation, eat your vegetables .... all of that is will help you avoid bugs just like this confusing part of the code:

First your query:

```
SELECT topic_id ...
```

Then when you retrieved:

```
$topic=$topicrow['id'];
```

print the query:

```
echo '<a href="topic.php?id=' . $topicrow['topic_id']
```

so go through your code and pay attention to details.